# Ruby Array Reference Function

Tags: arrays, ruby, reference, pass-by-reference

I don't understand the Ruby reference relationship of arrays variables (**best** and **vector**) with the return of the functions (**fitness** or **bitstring** for example).

Concidere this case:

```
best[:fitness]
```

At where **best** is array and **fitness** is a function, what will be required of the variable ? and what will be referenced by the function ?

See the complete code:

```
def objective_function(vector)
    return vector.inject(0.0) {|sum, x| sum + (x ** 2.0)}
end

def random_bitstring(num_bits)
    return (0...num_bits).inject(""){|s,i| s<<((rand<0.5) ? "1" : "0")}
end

def decode(bitstring, search_space, bits_per_param)
    vector = []
    search_space.each_with_index do |bounds, i|
        off, sum = i*bits_per_param, 0.0
        param = bitstring[off...(off+bits_per_param)].reverse
        param.size.times do |j|
            sum += ((param[j].chr=='1') ? 1.0 : 0.0) * (2.0 ** j.to_f)
        end
        min, max = bounds
        vector << min + ((max-min)/((2.0**bits_per_param.to_f)-1.0)) * sum
    end
    return vector
end

def fitness(candidate, search_space, param_bits)
    candidate[:vector]=decode(candidate[:bitstring], search_space, param_bits)
    candidate[:fitness] = objective_function(candidate[:vector])
end

def binary_tournament(pop)
    i, j = rand(pop.size), rand(pop.size)
    j = rand(pop.size) while j==i
    return (pop[i][:fitness] < pop[j][:fitness]) ? pop[i] : pop[j]
end

def point_mutation(bitstring, rate=1.0/bitstring.size)
    child = ""
    bitstring.size.times do |i|
        bit = bitstring[i].chr
        child << ((rand()<rate) ? ((bit=='1') ? "0" : "1") : bit)
    end
    return child
end

def crossover(parent1, parent2, rate)
    return ""+parent1 if rand()>=rate
    child = ""
    parent1.size.times do |i|
        child << ((rand()<0.5) ? parent1[i].chr : parent2[i].chr)
    end
    return child
end

def reproduce(selected, pop_size, p_cross, p_mut)
    children = []
    selected.each_with_index do |p1, i|
        p2 = (i.modulo(2)==0) ? selected[i+1] : selected[i-1]
        p2 = selected[0] if i == selected.size-1
        child = {}
        child[:bitstring] = crossover(p1[:bitstring], p2[:bitstring], p_cross)
        child[:bitstring] = point_mutation(child[:bitstring], p_mut)
        children << child
        break if children.size >= pop_size
    end
    return children
end

def bitclimber(child, search_space, p_mut, max_local_gens, bits_per_param)
    current = child
    max_local_gens.times do
        candidate = {}
        candidate[:bitstring] = point_mutation(current[:bitstring], p_mut)
        fitness(candidate, search_space, bits_per_param)
        current = candidate if candidate[:fitness] <= current[:fitness]
    end
    return current
end

def search(max_gens, search_space, pop_size, p_cross, p_mut, max_local_gens, p_local, bits_per_param=16)
    pop = Array.new(pop_size) do |i| {:bitstring=>random_bitstring(search_space.size*bits_per_param)}
    end
    pop.each{|candidate| fitness(candidate, search_space, bits_per_param) }
    gen, best = 0, pop.sort{|x,y| x[:fitness] <=> y[:fitness]}.first
    max_gens.times do |gen|
        selected = Array.new(pop_size){|i| binary_tournament(pop)}
        children = reproduce(selected, pop_size, p_cross, p_mut)
        children.each{|cand| fitness(cand, search_space, bits_per_param)}
        pop = []
        children.each do |child|
            if rand() < p_local
                child = bitclimber(child, search_space, p_mut, max_local_gens, bits_per_param)
            end
            pop << child
        end
        pop.sort!{|x,y| x[:fitness] <=> y[:fitness]}
        best = pop.first if pop.first[:fitness] <= best[:fitness]
        puts ">gen=#{gen}, f=#{best[:fitness]}, b=#{best[:bitstring]}"
    end
    return best
end

if __FILE__ == $0
    # problem configuration
    problem_size = 3
    search_space = Array.new(problem_size) {|i| [-5, +5]}
    # algorithm configuration
    max_gens = 100
    pop_size = 100
    p_cross = 0.98
    p_mut = 1.0/(problem_size*16).to_f
    max_local_gens = 20
    p_local = 0.5
    # execute the algorithm
    best = search(max_gens, search_space, pop_size, p_cross, p_mut, max_local_gens, p_local)
    puts "done! Solution: f=#{best[:fitness]}, b=#{best[:bitstring]}, v=#{best[:vector].inspect}"
end
```

**ps:** This code is an implementation of a Memetic Algorithms , which in turn is a variation of an Evolutionary Algorithm.
A Memetic Altorithms technically search the best solution to a problem in a number of solutions from an integrated global search results to an optimization every cycle / generation that selects variations of a good solution from a local search results.

My goal is to translate the code to Matlab programming.

Comment: `best` is not an array. It's a hash. `:fitness` is not a function either. It's just a symbol.